# Why is max-width container inside 100vw container causing overflow?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, user-interface

I am trying to make a header, body, and footer component in React. In each component is an outer-container and an inner-container.

HTML

```
<div className="outer-container">
   <div className="inner-container">
      lorem ipsum...etc
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
outer-container{
   width: 100vw;
   display: grid;
   justify-items: center;
}

inner-container{
   max-width: 1000px;
   width:100%;
}
```

The purpose is so that the inner container will cover and expand the full width of the browser until 1000px, then it will stop growing. This seems to work, but when I minimize to mobile view, I get a tiny bit of horizontal scrolling. Where is this overflowing coming from? I've removed all paddings and margins from body and tags.

When I set the outer-container width to 100%, the small gap disappears in mobile view, but now the outer-container and inner-container both stop at 1000px.

Comment: your code is working properly overflowing. maybe another class you havent mentioned is responsible for this. but you can use `overflow:-x hidden` to prevent horizontal scrolling

Comment: When you get vertical scrolling there is a little bit on the right taken up for the scrollbar (what this looks like and its width etc depends on the browser and device) so there has to be a little bit of horizontal scrolling introduced as the width remaining isn't the full 100vw;.

Comment: @AHaworth is there a solution to take into account the vertical scroll bar? i need the ability to scroll up and down.

Comment: The tiny amount of scrolling is down to the 1px either side that forms the border, hence the solution box-sizing: border-box which tells the browser to consider the border as part of the element's width and height.

Answer (score 1):

```
inner-container{
   max-width: 1000px;
   width:100%;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```